# Nuget: no compatible package found in active solution for MvvmCross.CrossCore

Tags: mvvmcross, nuget-package

I am trying to install MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.14 into a WindowsPhone 8.0 class library from the NuGet command line.  Error I get when attempting to do this is:

```
PM> install-package MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.14
install-package : No compatible project(s) found in the active solution.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.14
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoCompatibleProjects,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

In this solution, I have another a Windows Phone 8 application project (Target Windows Phone OS Version is set to Windows Phone OS 8.0) that has the following MvvmCross packages installed.  This was done earlier without any problems:

```
<packages>
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Location" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Messenger" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Sqlite" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Visibility" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.PortableSupport" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="WPtoolkit" version="4.2013.08.16" targetFramework="wp80" />
</packages>
```

Anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am having same sort of problem

Comment: Arrgh, I simply cannot remember how I got around this.  Will update answer question if I stumble across the solution.  I need to start doing a better job of tracking/answering questions here..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I just had a similar issue and I'd missed a - from the command. It seems like you might have done something similar.

I was trying 
`install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost version 5.1.2`

And I resolved it by doing

`install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -version 5.1.2 -project GRP2App.Web`

Note, I'd missed the - from the `version` parameter. I also added the `project` parameter but I don't think it was important.

Your command `install-package MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.14` doesn't have `-version` before the version number.

Comment: Indeed, that did it for me too.  Was missing a dash before the version.  Had version 3.0.14 instead of -version 3.0.14.  Weird error.  Thanks.

Comment: Just found that you also get the same error with an extra - (so I had `uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost --removedependencies`. - Been using something or other that likes `--` args!

Comment: This problem had been driving me nuts, somewhere along the line, I'd got it into my head that I needed to use two dashes, ie '--version', which also causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I ve got this error when trying to install to a project incorrectly spelled:

```
Install-Package 'Package' -ProjectName 'WrongName' -Version 1.0.0
```

When I fixed project spelling, all worked fine:

```
Install-Package 'Package' -ProjectName 'CorrectName' -Version 1.0.0
```